Removing 2 leading zeros from a field
This should be easy but I haven't gotten it to work.
The data in a column has six characters. I just need to trim the left-most two characters, which are '00'.
I'm trying the statement below but only get '0' as a result.
SELECT SUBSTRING (LOGRECNO, 3, len(4))
    from [dbo].[DECENNIAL2010]
    where LOGRECNO like '000%'

I was expected the right-most 4 characters from the field

What do you expect len(4) to return exactly? If you want four characters you just want 4; len(4) = LEN('4') = 1.

"I was expected the right-most 4 characters from the field" => RIGHT() ??

select len(4), len('4'), len(N'4'); returns 1 for each expression. From SUBSTRING: "If the sum of start and length is greater than the number of characters in expression, the whole value expression beginning at start is returned." In other words, if you use 6 (or 10) as the third argument you will get the rest of the string.

SELECT RIGHT(LOGRECNO, 4)
FROM [dbo].[DECENNIAL2010]
WHERE LOGRECNO LIKE '000%'

This will return the last 4 characters from the LOGRECNO field for all records where LOGRECNO starts with ‘000’. The RIGHT function is specifically designed to extract a specified number of characters from the right end of a string.

    SELECT case 
             when LOGRECNO like '00%' then RIGHT(LOGRECNO, 4) --or SUBSTRING (LOGRECNO, 3, 4)
             else LOGRECNO 
           end as LOGRECNO
      from [dbo].[DECENNIAL2010]


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Thanks for your good suggestion,
Since the user has asked:
" ..., I just need to trim the left-most two characters, which are '00' "
this answer only trims the rows whose two left digits of LOGRECNO column re 00, and the rest of the rows that do not have this condition are displayed as they were.
